# Playing audio from a .mov file with Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Basically, my app allows the user to select a video from photo library, and I want to be able to play back the audio exclusively. However, AVAudioPlayer doesn't seem to accept .mov file paths, is there any way to work around this??

Comment: Use `AVPlayer`.

Comment: I think this is all in Objective-C, but check [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+extract+audio+mov+file) about extracting audio from a mov file.